# Android: WakeLock only for internet connection?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

My app uses a service which needs internet connection to work in the background. However, when android goes to sleep, my service cannot access internet anymore. I've seen that wakelock can fix it, but it seems to be an overkill for just keeping the network up. Is there any other way to achieve this?

How does apps like whatsapp handle this?

Comment: Will [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) come handy for you? It will kick in when certain constrains are fulfiled, among which is internet connection.

Comment: @azizbekian Its not that internet connection is cut off, my service goes offline. The service cannot access internet.

Comment: @mehulmpt any solution ?

Comment: Got any solution for this @mehulmpt? I'm facing a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47954615/1259763

Answer (score 0):

```
      namespace blablabla
  {
  [BroadcastReceiver]
public class blablabla : BroadcastReceiver
{
    

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Full, 
        "BackgroundReceiver");
        wakeLock.Acquire();

        //var context = this.ApplicationContext;
        WifiManager wifiManager = 
       (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService("wifi");
        WifiLock mWifiLock = 
        wifiManager.CreateWifiLock(Android.Net.WifiMode.Full, "WifiLock");
        mWifiLock.Acquire();


        //you code



       mWifiLock.Release();
        wakeLock.Release();

    }}}
```

answer for other people looking for